# Haskell rank n types & type classes syntax

Tags: haskell, polymorphism

While learning Haskell I'm trying to understand the types of clojure's transducers in Haskell.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}

module Transducers where

-- r = reduced
type Reducer r a = r -> a -> r

type Transducer a b = forall r . Reducer r a -> Reducer r b
```

I'm having trouble understanding how to type the following function:

```
-- type inference
transduce :: Foldable t => (t1 -> b -> a -> b) -> t1 -> b -> t a -> b
-- what I actually want
transduce :: forall t1 . Foldable t => Transducer a b -> t1 -> b -> t a -> b
transduce xform f init coll = foldl (xform f) init coll
```

This gives me trouble, it won't compile. Am I missing something syntax-wise? Or isn't this possible?

Comment: Can you give a more complete example of what you are trying to do? Why not just have `transduce :: Foldable t => Transducer a b -> Reducer r a -> r -> t b -> r` ?

Comment: Clearly the type `Foldable t => Transducer a b -> t1 -> b -> t a -> b` is the wrong one for the given implementation. `xform` has type `Transducer a b` which is a function taking a `Reducer r0 a` for some `r0`, but you apply `xform` to `f` which has type `t1` (a rigid type!), which obviously doesn't make sense. The inferred type `Foldable t => (t1 -> b -> a -> b) -> t1 -> b -> t a -> b` is probably what you actually want - the first argument isn't a transducer, but you can pass something which is a transducer. If you want inference to guess polytypes, wrap `Transducer` in a newtype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you probably meant something like

```
transduce :: Foldable t => Transducer a b -> Reducer r a -> r -> t b -> r
```

As [user2407038 suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39719073/haskell-rank-n-types-type-classes-syntax#comment66745742_39719073), you only need such a fancy type if you want to force the caller to supply a `Transducer`. Otherwise, you can simplify it to

```
transduce :: Foldable t => (x -> Reducer r b) -> x -> r -> t b -> r
```

Comment: Thanks, I understand now :)